# Meaning of 獨行道 in English

Tags: meaning, words

The translation of 獨行道(Dokkodo) is literally "The path of aloneness" or is it something else?

Answer (score 2):

- 獨 (独 in modern Japanese): alone, lone
- 行: go
- 道: way, path

So a character-by-character translation would be "lone-going-way", "way to go alone" or "way of going alone". (But that doesn't mean "the path of aloneness" is wrong.)